# Como selecionar dado único de uma condicional join?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Tenho 2 tabelas de banco de dados:

**servers**

```
+----------+--------------+
| Field    | Type         |
+----------+--------------+
| id       | int(11)      |
| ip       | varchar(255) |
| votes    | int(11)      |
| port     | varchar(255) |
| hash     | varchar(255) |
| created  | datetime     |
| modified | datetime     |
+----------+--------------+
```

**stats**

```
+------------+--------------+
| Field      | Type         |
+------------+--------------+
| id         | int(11)      |
| server_id  | int(11)      |
| type       | varchar(255) |
| hostname   | varchar(255) |
| gamemode   | varchar(255) |
| language   | varchar(255) |
| players    | int(11)      |
| slots      | int(11)      |
| version    | varchar(255) |
| url        | varchar(255) |
| date_check | datetime     |
| created    | datetime     |
| modified   | datetime     |
+------------+--------------+
```

Estou tendo problemas para fazer a seguinte regra de seleção:

Selecionar os dados da tabela *servers* e fazer um join com os *stats* utilizando o *servers.id = stats.server_id*. Porém esse join só deve pegar o **dado mais recente (apenas um)** da tabela **stats** que tenha o **type** igual a *online* ou *offline*.

Como poderia ser a query utilizada para fazer essa regra?

Comment: Você quer quais dados de cada tabela?

Comment: Você tem exemplos de dados: de como é e de como teria que ficar?

Comment: Qual é o campo que define que o dado é mais recente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja como fazer abaixo, essa solução foi feita em SQL SERVER, mas o select é equivalente para o mysql.

```
declare  @servers table
(
     id        int,      
     ip        varchar(255) ,
     votes     int,      
     port      varchar(255), 
     hash      varchar(255), 
     created   datetime ,    
     modified  datetime    
)

declare @stats table
(
     id          int,      
     server_id   int,      
     type        varchar(255), 
     hostname    varchar(255), 
     gamemode    varchar(255), 
     language    varchar(255), 
     players     int,      
     slots       int,     
     version     varchar(255),
     url         varchar(255), 
     date_check  datetime,     
     created     datetime,     
     modified    datetime     
)

insert into @servers values
(1,'162.198.1.1',12,'80','3232323',getdate(), getdate()),
(2,'162.198.1.1',12,'8080','3232323',getdate(), getdate())

insert into @stats values
(1,1,'offline', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -4, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(2,1,'online ', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -3, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(3,1,'online ', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(4,1,'offline', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(5,1,'não select', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),getdate(), getdate()),
(11,1,'offline', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),getdate(), getdate()),

(6,2,'offline', 'teste/teste2','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -4, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(7,2,'offline', 'teste/teste2','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -3, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(8,2,'offline', 'teste/teste2','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(9,2,'offline', 'teste/teste2','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120), getdate()),
(10,2,'online', 'teste/teste2','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),getdate(), getdate()),
(12,2,'não select', 'teste/teste','','',1,1,'','',getdate(),getdate(), getdate())


select * from @servers sv
join @stats s
on s.server_id = sv.id
and s.created = (select max(created) from @stats s1 where s1.server_id = sv.id)
where s.type in ('online','offline')
```

Answer (score 1):

Vê se ajuda?

```
select sv.*
from servers sv
       inner join stats st
         on st.server_id = sv.id
where st.type in ('inline','offline')
order by st.modified desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Ajudou sim e muito! Infelizmente nao posso te dar reputação pois nao tenho conta aqui (e estou com preguiça de criar uma) mas se um dia criar com certeza vou te reputar!

Comment: O importante é ter resolvido. Abs!